Fano Fibration example
My professor's notes define Fano fibration as a morphism between connected varieties $X \to Y$ such that the general fibre is Fano (i.e it is smooth and $K$ is antiample). I'm wondering why he added the adjective "general"?

Can there be a morphism such that a special fibre is not Fano but a general fibre is?


If the above is indeed true, then can we add extra conditions that forces all fibres to be Fano?


Fix a line $L \subset \mathbb P^2$ and two points $p,q$ not on $L$. Now let $x \in L$ denote a moving point. Now consider the projection $\pi:\mathbb P^2 \times L \to L$; from our fixed points we obtain two constant sections $\left\{p\right\}\times L$ and $\left\{q\right\}\times L$, and from our moving point we obtain a nonconstant section. Let $X$ denote the blowup of $\mathbb P^2 \times L$ along these three sections, and let $\tilde\pi:X \to L$. The fiber of $\tilde\pi$ over a general point of $L$ is a del Pezzo (i.e. Fano) surface of degree $6$ since $x,p,$ and $q$ are not collinear. But when $x$ is $L \cap \overline{pq}$, the three points are collinear and the anticanonical divisor is no longer ample as explained here: Blow-up of projective plane in three collinear points is not a del Pezzo surface
